# How to escape slot in IBM watson assistant?

Tags: websphere, chatbot, ibm-watson, slot, watson-assistant

I want to know how to escape while using slot
for example, there is a slot need entities  @time, @date, @place
so user said "next sunday, in the market"
In this moment, not include @time. so slot asked "I need time information too"
but user doesn't answer about time, just input "main menu" because he want to go main node (welcome message)
In conclusion, I wanna make when user in slot, but input other intent, just quit slot(Ignore all data from slot) and go intent node.

How can I do that? It's seem to be impossible..

Comment: Could you structure and reformat your question? Do you mean a so-called digressions? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-digressions

Comment: not digressions. no need return, i just want going other node immediately using input intent. Even while we are in the slot now

Comment: that is part of digression, there are options on how to handle it - you can only jump to high-level / root nodes

Comment: when I using digression, Even right answer input(answer with the entity checked by the requested question) but jumps to another node(ex, I don't know node..)

Comment: Please share details of your dialog (intents, entities, dialog conditions, user input) and the result. Is it in "Try it" or in testing with an app or preview? Have you cleared input between retries?

Comment: sorry for late henrik, and I'm sorry for my poor explanation. I couldn't upload watson node because of security problem(not allowed anything in this place....) but I finally found a way i need! thanks your help

Answer (score 2):

As @data_henrik suggests the way to handle this is through a digression. When you hit the "I don't know what time" or : "go back to the main menu" digression, you can perform operations to break out of the slot operation.

There are a number of ways to break of slots:

- You can clear the dialog stack - `<? clearDialogStack() ?>` which will go back to the beginning.
- You could set the required time field to a temporary value; set some handling variables; then handle the redirection in a post slots node, which checks for digression set variables.

Comment: when I using digression, Even right answer input(answer with the entity checked by the requested question) but jumps to another node(ex, I don't know node..)

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: sorry for late chughts, and I'm sorry for my poor explanation. I couldn't upload watson node because of security problem(not allowed anything in this place....) but I finally found a way i need! thanks your help